# Phone is defined as string in db schema, but integers are saving as valid in Ruby

Tags: ruby, database, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here...

My db schema:

```
create_table "plans", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "phone1"
  ...
end
```

Here's a snippet from my console:

```
@plan = Plan.create(a bunch of params)
@plan.phone1 = "123"
@plan.valid?
# => true

# above is great, here's where the problem comes in:
@plan.update_attribute("phone1", 123)
@plan.phone1
# => 123
@plan.valid?
# => true
```

This is not making my model tests very happy. Nor me for that matter. From my model, here are all the relevant validations:

```
validates :phone1, presence: true
validates :phone1, length: { is: 3 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue. After the model is saved, do you get back a string? ... It seems to me that the length is more than three and that the data will be saved into the DB as a string.

Comment: After the model is saved I get back a Fixnum, which I don't want because 1) I need to do other things later in my model that uses string not Fixednum. 2) Saving this as a Fixnum risks errors like "024" which can be saved only as a string

Comment: if you get a Fixnum when you **reload** the model from the schema (not just after saving it), than something might be wrong with the DB's definitions. Are you sure the field is defined as a string? (Did you successfully migrate from an older version where the field was numerical?) ...

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord looks at your `schema.rb` and creates setters which typecast based on the column value.

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  # "Automagically" creating by Active Record.
  # def phone1= val
  #   @phone1 = val.to_s
  # end
end
```

So when you call `.valid` on `@plan` the 'phone1' attribute is a string. I'm not sure what your test looks like but if your are doing:

```
plan = Plan.new(123)
expect(plan.valid?).to be_falsy
```

Expecting plan to be invalid solely because it's passed a number than your have simply misunderstood how rails works.

Given:

```
$ rails g model plan phone1:string ends:datetime
$ rails g migrate
```

---

```
irb(main):004:0>@plan = Plan.create(ends: Date.tomorrow, phone1: 123)
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "plans" ("ends", "phone1", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["ends", "2015-06-24 00:00:00.000000"], ["phone1", "123"], ["created_at", "2015-06-23 02:21:39.236332"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-23 02:21:39.236332"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Plan id: 2, phone1: "123", ends: "2015-06-24 00:00:00", created_at: "2015-06-23 02:21:39", updated_at: "2015-06-23 02:21:39">
irb(main):005:0> @plan.phone1 = 123456
=> 123456
irb(main):006:0> @plan.phone1.class
=> String
irb(main):007:0> @plan.update_attribute("phone1", 123)
   (0.8ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):008:0> @plan.phone1.class
=> String
irb(main):013:0> @plan.ends = "2015-06-23"
=> "2015-06-23"
irb(main):014:0> @plan.ends
=> Tue, 23 Jun 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):015:0>
```

Comment: This is a great explanation with examples. I had totally not realized this before , thanks!

Comment: It think what helped me realize how the ActiveRecord "magic" works is ironically Monogoid. It also uses metaprogramming to create  setters and getters in the model and more but it's a bit more apparent since you define fields in the model - instead of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validation method to check that `phone1` is a `String`*:

```
class Plan
   validates :phone1, presence: true
   validates :phone1, length: { is: 3 }
   validates :special_validations

   def special_validations
      errors.add(:phone1, "Must be String") unless phone1.is_a? String
      # add whatever you feel like
      true
   def
end
```

On the other hand, if you get a numerical field when loading the data from the database, than your database's field type isn't a string. Maybe an older setting persists?

---

* I'm not too savvy as far as the Rails specialty features go, so there might be a shortcut to this...

Comment: You were totally right, it was a reload incident. It's just very interesting behavior... so Rails will apparently take integers and auto convert them to string....

Comment: Type casting will be attempted when saving to the DB. Numeric to String is one example. It's also true for String to Date and other types. I'm not sure at what point in the validation workflow the typecasting is attempted or if the Numeric to String is a happy mistake.

Comment: Since AR typecasts in the setters which it creates on the model `special_validations` would only add an error if `phone1` was nil or if you did something really silly like [page.instance_variable_set(:@phone1, 50)](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) which skirts the setter. But otherwise is a good attempt...